# storing data from jtable into array

Tags: java, swing, jtable, numberformatexception

I'm using `jtable` in my application.I want to store `jtable` data into array.while i'm entering data into table and when i press delete button to delete the data in the cell and click the button to store data into array, it shows error `NumberFormatException` because of pressing delete button.How can i solve this? My code is

```
        int source = 0;
        int temp = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int dist = 0;
        adjacencyMatrix = new int[nodes][nodes];
        for (int row = 0; row < dtm.getRowCount(); row++) {
            for (int col = 1; col < dtm.getColumnCount(); col++) {

                if (dtm.getValueAt(row, col) == null || (dtm.getValueAt(row, col) == "") || (dtm.getValueAt(row, col) == " ")) {
                    adjacencyMatrix[row][col - 1] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                } else {

                    adjacencyMatrix[row][col - 1] = Integer.parseInt((String) dtm.getValueAt(row, col));
                    // System.out.println("row ----" + row + "------" + (col - 1) + "------" + adjacencyMatrix[row][col - 1]);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

Comment: What line does the exception occur? Whenever you get an exception, and it is related to the question, post the stack trace and let us know what line the exception occurs.

Comment: Odds are it's the `Integer.parseInt()` method. The String you're passing in is probably not an Integer (could be a float or double).

Comment: @Gorb I agree. The OP talks about deleting a cell. Which _would_ cause a NFE when attempting to parse nothing.

Comment: What I don't get though is why do you even need to store the data in a different array. Your `TableModel` is already a data structure holding the data

Comment: (dtm.getValueAt(row, col) == "") || (dtm.getValueAt(row, col) == " ")
To compare Strings in Java, use equals().

Comment: @peeskillet: didn't even think of a null object, that's even more likely. +1

Comment: In addition to @Tarmo's comment, you can replace this `(dtm.getValueAt(row, col) == "") || (dtm.getValueAt(row, col) == " ")` by `dtm.getValueAt(row,col).toString().trim().isEmpty()`. It covers every case of empty string (non spaces, 1 space, 2 spaces, ..., n spaces).